# Bash print array element characters vertically side by side

Tags: arrays, bash, printing, printf, echo

I have an array that i want to print vertically but also side by side.
Ex.

I have an array with these elements as follows separated by spaces and each character in the element separated by commas:
`0,1,2   3,4,5   6,7,8`

I want it to output:

```
036
147
258
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ary=(0,1,2   3,4,5   6,7,8)
pr -T -"${#ary[@]}" < <(IFS=,; echo "${ary[*]}" | tr , '\n') | tr -d '[:blank:]'
```

prints

```
036
147
258
```

Notes:

- the `< <(...)` syntax is a redirection (first `<`) of a [process substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Process-Substitution)
- the bit inside the process substitution prints the array elements joined with a comma then translates the commas into newlines
- the output of the process substitution (a single column of digits) is redirected into `pr`.
- [`pr`](http://man.cx/pr) is a handy tool for forcing a column of output into columns.
- the `-"${#ary[@]}"` option tells `pr` to use the same number of columns as there are array elements.
- the output of `pr` is sent to a second `tr`, that deletes any horizontal whitespace.

If you want commas, <strike>change the second `tr` to: `tr -s '[:blank:]' ,`</strike> use this:

```
pr -T -s, -"${#ary[@]}" < <(IFS=,; echo "${ary[*]}" | tr , '\n')
```

Comment: Is there a way to keep the commas separating each character in the output? And would you mind explaining the solution? Thanks for the help!

Comment: For keeping commas adding `-s,` to the `pr` command also works and means the final `tr` can be dropped entirely.